# Website Developing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have developed a website using JSP n Servlets, now i want to make my website dynamic, like city wise content should change (for example i have different list of contents for different cities when a user select some city XYZ my website should display only tat particular XYZ city's content rest of the contents should hide or shouldn't display). How to do this functionality. I was thinking about **div hide and show** concept but my content in webpage is huge it won't affect performance? if it is not how to achieve this with example. and if their is any other concept please guide me how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Yes, using hide and show would result in huge performance problems. What I would suggest is: 1. Create a search bar. 2. User types city name, then presses "Search". 3. Call an API (or fetch data from your backend), then render it on the page.

Comment: @Zevgon Ur approach is sothing similar and thanks , It will be appreciated if u elaborate how to store content in API and call the same in a page. Thanks

Comment: There are many options. If you're creating a light-weight app with very little user-specific customization, and you don't need to store data yourself, you can probably get away with using APIs such as [this one for weather](https://openweathermap.org/api). Otherwise, I would suggest creating a backend, which is much more complicated. Some popular ones are [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (Python), [Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597140/understanding-how-to-use-nodejs-to-create-a-simple-backend) (JavaScript), and [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) (Ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, you can stored those data in database, or in json/xml/text file.

Then, when user choose different cities, you load the content out regarding user's choice.

You can try with web API, and other basic knowledge of web services as well as database / noSQL.

If you have multiple cities in your display list, it will take a lot of time to load your page

Finally, you should change the question tags, questions Header to identify easily

**UPDATE:**
If you really insist on using javascript to show/hide the City content, then you can try with my example: [Show/hide div with javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/jackyle/tyst76st/)

I wrote a simple one ( of course not the most optimize) so you can imagine how can it be done.

```
var cityList = ["City1", "City2", "City3"];
var citypick = document.getElementById('mySelect');
citypick.onchange= displayFunction;

function displayFunction() {
    for(var i =0; i< cityList.length;i++){
      var selectCity = document.getElementById(cityList[i]);
      if(selectCity.id == citypick.value){
        selectCity.style.display = 'block';
      }
      else{
        selectCity.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: my website contents are not that much huge where we can use DB. in webpage only we can manage but my question is how to manage those divisions thorugh hide and show methods or something else concept ?

Comment: @Baasu check my update answer then

Comment: Thank you @Jacky it hepls me

Comment: You have done it by selector , can we do the same in text box ?? and if i want get city in one jsp page and want to control it in different jsp page how can i achieve this ??

Comment: @Baasu What do you mean by doing the same for textbox? Yes of course, by using ID selector and catching the change event, you can do whatever you want. It will be easier, if you use jquery instead of pure javascript. Secondly, do you mean the 1st jsp will be the control page, then when user choose the city, it will load to another page that contain City's content?